# Can I use these old supply valves under my kitchen sink to install a new modern faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I have this old set of valves/fittings running up to my Moen kitchen faucet that I believe has been in this house since the late 80s and the faucet is no longer giving me hot water correctly, and leaks a bit. I would like to replace it with a new faucet, but I have some really old valves under there that have compression fittings going into them for that faucet, rather than more modern braided/threaded tubes.

**Hot:**
[image]
**Cold:**
[image]

My question: when I get a new faucet, what kind of pipes/fittings (and sizes) should I consider?

- will braided tubes work? Something tells me no, but I'm hoping its this simple.. but I'm not sure you can screw a regular braided fitting onto something that is using compression ones
- if I do have to use a compression fitting + pipes, can I use these existing pipes here that it has with a modern faucet?
- what size should everything be? That might be impossible to tell from these pictures,  but to me it looks like the standard size that modern faucets use..
- should I just install newer, modern valves (ugh)

**The old faucet:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are brass shutoff valves and if they work, completely turns off the water when closed, they'll be OK and you could use the braided connecting tubes on them, just remove the compression nut. However, It looks like you have these valves compression fitted to the supply line so it would be really easy to replace them since you're installing new faucet. You'd have to be able to turn off the water to the entire house to replace them. The existing gray tubes could be used but many insurance companies don't like them and you'll take a hit on your 4-point inspection so do yourself a favor and use the braided connecting tubes, plus, they are much easier to install. The size of everything will depend on the fittings on the faucet you buy. The supply lines look like a 1/2" copper line.

Comment: They do work and are able to completely turn off the water. You're right, I could replace them, I'm just a bit nervous to since I've not done it before. You are correct that they are compression fitted to the supply line... I am unsure as well about removing the ferrule on the original line, I know those can't be reused or it'll leak.

Since the hot water side doesn't work on the faucet anymore anyway, I was considering just getting a new faucet, removing the nut on the hot side and seeing if the braided tubes the faucet comes with fit before doing more work.

Comment: @shayl  Have you considered just replacing the cartridge in the faucet?  Maybe not if you get nervous being a newbe.  Replacing just the faucet will be just fine since the shutoff valves work. You can always change them in the future after you get a little experience. We'll  be here to help.

Comment: I considered taking the faucet apart,  but its really old and kind of yucky so I thought it might just be nicer to get a new one.